# Problems with overflow: hidden and text-overflow: ellipsis

Tags: html, css, overflow

I've got the follwoing HTML markup:

```
    <div class="todo-item">
        <div class="todo-complete-box"></div>
        <div class="todo-item-title">Do something, do something,Do something, do something,Do something, do something,Do something, do something,Do something, do something,Do something, do something,Do something, do something,Do something, do something,Do something, do something,Do something, do something,Do something, do something,Do something, do something,Do something, do something,Do something, do something,Do something, do something,Do something, do something,Do something, do something,Do something, do something,Do something, do something,Do something, do something
        </div>
    </div>
```

And the following CSS:

```
div.todo-item{
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 7px;
    height: 45px;
    max-height: 45px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
div.todo-complete-box{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 2px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    position: relative;
    top: 5.5px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
div.todo-item-title{
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

The `<div class="todo-item">` is just a container. It's width is 100%.
I added the `white-space: nowrap;` and `overflow: hidden` properties to it,  so that when the title in the `<div class="todo-item-title">` is too long, it doesn't go out of the box.

Now it looks like this:

[image: Without text-overflow]

But when I add the `text-overflow: ellipsis;` property to the `<div class="todo-item">` element:

```
div.todo-item{
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

, it looks like this:

[image: With text-overflow]

**As far as I know the 3 dots should be displayed at the end of the text, and not just replace the text alltogether** (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_text-overflow&preval=ellipsis)

What's the problem here?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `overflow:hidden;` to the element and reduce `max-width:90%;`.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/as8wfk3c/1/)

```
div.todo-item-title {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 90%;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Put the ellipsis onto the .todo-item-title (the container for the text, rather than the parent).

Here's a working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/fvuuLegL/

```
div.todo-item-title{
 display: block; position:absolute; left: 0px; top:13px; padding-left:44px;
 max-width: 100%;
 white-space: nowrap;
 overflow: hidden;
 text-overflow:ellipsis; 
}
```

Also changed your css a bit so it uses relative and absolute positioning within the box, so nothing can fall out of alignment.